# In backbone.js how can I catch all events except the plain "change" event?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

When I bind to the "all" event and some property changes, i receive 2 events: the "change:property" event and the plain "change" event. Since I always catch the property specific event , I dont need the plain one. I cannot bind to all "change:*" individually because i dont know beforehand all the properties that might get added to the model. So is there any way to stay with model.bind("all", ...) and somehow get rid of the "change" event?

P.S. I know I can filter the name in the handler, I am asking if there is a more standard way of filtering or declaring events in models, that I dont know of.

Comment: This issue was solved. Check it out [here] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457694/backbone-catch-all-events-except-somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can't you just use the `change` event and then check what attributes have changed by accessing the `changedAttributes` method (during the propagation of change event it will return you a hash of only the attributes that have changed during this change event - [see more here](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changedAttributes)). I believe this is the cleanest way to handle that - at least based on the details provided.

Comment: Actually, I dont know how i ve missed this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the only way is to manually add a filter

```
ModelA = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.bind('all', this.onChange, this);
  },

  onChange: function() {
    //apply your filter
  }
});
```

Comment: In case you want to attach different call back to different event you can attach different change function on different event.