# Catch all events except in reset

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, coffeescript

I wanna catch all events except 'reset'. I've a code like this initialized inside a View.

```
messagesCollection.on 'all', @_handleMessageChanges, @
```

Right now it works for all events. As I've mentioned above I don't need to catch in a reset event.

How can I resolve this issue? Please help us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `all`, the first argument is the `event`. So, you can do

```
_handleMessageChanges: function(event, ...) {
    if ( event === 'reset' ) return;
}
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/nxs9q/1

From the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog):

> "all" — this special event fires for any triggered event, passing the
>   event name as the first argument.